# Условия в preg_replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Можно ли решить такую задачу одним preg_replace

```
if(preg_match('~(\d{1,2})\.?\d?"~iu',$text,$dataf)){
    if($dataf[1]>16) $dataf[1] = '17" и более';
    elseif($dataf[1]<11) $dataf[1] = 'до 11"';  
    else $dataf[1] = $dataf[1].'"-'.$dataf[1].'.9"';
}
$text = preg_replace('~(\d{1,2})\.?\d?"~iu',$dataf[1],$text);
```

Comment: Какую именно задачу то?

Comment: Задача переписать данное решение с помощью только preg_replace, используя, например, условия и логические выражения

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
preg_replace_callback('~(\d{1,2})\.?\d?"~',function($dataf) {
    if($dataf[1]>16) return '17" и более';
    elseif($dataf[1]<11) return 'до 11"';  
    else return $dataf[1] = $dataf[1].'"-'.$dataf[1].'.9"';
}, $text);
```

См. [демо](https://ideone.com/JST8Yh).

Тут `$dataf` является массивом, содержащим совпадение со всеми захваченными подстроками. Анонимная функция возвращает нужное значение при выполнении заданных условий.

Comment: Хотел использовать условия в preg_replace без callback функции. Но не знаю как :) Может есть какое-то решение? C callback решается просто, но примерно так же, как и без него.

Comment: @sergvm Да, можно и с `preg_replace`, но почему? Откуда такое требование?

Comment: Хочу по максимуму сократить количество кода :)

Comment: @sergvm Не думаю, что вы можете обойтись без `preg_replace_callback`, здесь несколько вариантов замены.

Comment: Спасибо за диалог :)